# Detect word and page of occurrence in Word Document

Tags: python, regex, ms-word

I am trying to detect specific words (with a regex pattern that I already have) in a Word Document. I do not only want to detect the word but also to know in which page it appears, I think of something like a list of tuples: [(WordA, 10), (WordB, 4) ....]

I am able to extract the text from the word document and detect all the words that match the regex pattern but I am not able to know if which page the word appears. Also, I want to detect all the occurrences regardless if they appear in the header, body or footnotes.

Here is my regex pattern:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\bDOC[-–—]\d{9}(?!\d)')
```

Extraction of text:

```
import docx2txt
 
result = docx2txt.process("Word_Document.docx")
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: and how do you expect to know the page if you convert it to a text format? the text format is unlikely to contain pagination (unless maybe you have numbered your pages, then perhaps there is a chance) otherwise you have to find the text in the word document and find page from that somehow

Comment: Yes, that's an issue and I see your point but maybe you can propose a different library to handle word document as such, for example win32? I do not have experience with it so I ask the more experienced community

Comment: can't really ask for recommendations of libraries but for example if you can distinguish page breaks in the text file (some special character maybe?) then you can count those to get the page count or maybe the library has its own methods, maybe look at how `process` function works? how it extracts the data, that may help

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Matiiss but the process method does not bring any information (nor the page number).

Comment: Regex just finds matches in a text. To get pages, you need to split the text into pages, and search for your matches on each page.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, good point. An idea that I had in mind but I was wondering if someone knew of a library that handle all of that and provide all the information from a Word Document.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to say thank you to those who tried to answer this question. I found two solutions:

1. With Word Documents, splitting them into one word document per page with Aspose:
   https://products.aspose.cloud/words/python/split/
2. Convert the Word Document into PDF and then create one PDF per page with PyPDF2 or other library
   E

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a while of trying to figure this out, I managed to get this:

```py
import docx2txt.docx2txt as docx2txt
import re

page_contents = []


def xml2text(xml):
    text = u''
    root = docx2txt.ET.fromstring(xml)
    start = 0
    for child in root.iter():
        if child.tag == docx2txt.qn('w:t'):
            t_text = child.text
            text += t_text if t_text is not None else ''
        elif child.tag == docx2txt.qn('w:tab'):
            text += '\t'
        elif child.tag in (docx2txt.qn('w:br'), docx2txt.qn('w:cr')):
            text += '\n'
        elif child.tag == docx2txt.qn("w:p"):
            text += '\n\n'
        elif child.tag == docx2txt.qn('w:lastRenderedPageBreak'):
            end = len(text) + 1
            page_contents.append(text[start:end])
            start = len(text)
    page_contents.append(text[start:len(text) + 1])
    return text


docx2txt.xml2text = xml2text
docx2txt.process('test_file.docx')  # use your filename

matches = []
pattern = re.compile(r'\bDOC[-–—]\d{9}(?!\d)')
for page_num, page_content in enumerate(page_contents, start=1):
    # do regex search
    all_matches = pattern.findall(page_content)
    if all_matches:
        for match in all_matches:
            matches.append((match, page_num))

print(matches)
```

It modifies the module's function so that when it is called it will add each page to a list and the index + 1 will be the page number. It modifies the module's xml2text parser to additionally detect a page break and then add that pages contents to the local global list. It uses the tag `'lastRenderedPageBreak'`, the slight caution is to save the file if you have edited it so that the placement of these tags also gets updated.

Comment: Thanks Matiiss, this is very nice. I have performed some quick checks and I can see that (for my .docx) the list detects the first pattern at page 45 but it actually happens in page 28. There is some kind of 17/18 pages mismatch. One thing that I have found is the Aspose library (pay) and convert the doc into a PDF in order to do what Wiktor proposed

Comment: @Enterrador99 great you found a solution, I can't tell you why that may have happened but I guess it is something with the document and not something I may be able to fix so great you found that library (maybe there is a free library that does the same but I don't know), good luck